# Как убрать нижнюю панель навигации Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Я хочу убрать нижнюю панель навигации. Пробую сделать так:

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus) {
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
        }
    }
```

Но тогда панель, где время, процент заряда и так далее наезжает на активити.
Если сделать так:

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus) {
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
        }
    }
```

то панель с временем тоже уйдёт, точнее станет чёрной. Но тогда каждый раз при переходе в другую активити она будет дёрганной. Можно ли как-то убрать только нижнюю панель, не трогая при этом панель с временем?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так :

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```